# How to use wso2is features through API calls from my application

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

our team is developing a web based system. we wish to use WSO2IS for user management. I installed WSO2IS as in its official site. Now I want to know how to use its features through API calls from my application

I have started the WSO2IS server locally

https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/index.jsp?loginStatus=true.

I expect to communicate with WSO2IS through API call. But I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Using+APIs) you will be able to get a basic idea on WSO2 IS related APIs.

Comment: This is a link-only answer.